# Why are all the keys on my piano registering as one below what they actually are?

Tags: piano, tuning

My acoustic Eavestaff Pianette, which has not been tuned in over 20 years, has gone out of tune precisely one whole-step low. For example, G4 is F4, A4 is G4, B4 is A4, and so on. I have used two different tuning devices, and it is the same on both.

What would cause it to go so evenly out of tune?

Comment: How old is the piano? And when was the last tuning?

Comment: Acoustic piano or digital?

Comment: If it is an electronic piano you might have inadvertently set the transposition feature to minus 2.

Comment: ACOUSTIC EAVESTAFF PIANETTE over 20 yrs old last tuned - A long time ago!

Comment: Should I just tune all keys to one below what they actually are?

Comment: Please hire a professional piano technician. You may need more than one tuning (at a spaced interval) to get back to pitch.

Comment: If it is still playable it must have been tuned a whole tone lower. Could you compare the tuning pitch with any instrument, e.g. a treble recorder?

Comment: Is the whole piano in tune with itself? Doubtful. Nothing we can do about it. It needs a good piano tuner to visit.

Comment: A tangential bit of information from [AA Piano Tuners UK](http://www.aatuners.com/eavestaff-mini-piano-problems.html): "As attractive and luring as they are, many of these pianos CANNOT be tuned or serviced anymore." Other sites make similar comments.